# Training a neural network with partial labeling

Tags: neural-networks, multiarmed-bandit

I want to train a neural network that is part of a multi-armed bandit problem. 
For each data sample, I have some features representing the context of the sample and there are x neurons in the output layer that represents the reward for this context for a specific action (each neuron represents an action).
The issue is that for each sample, I know only the reward (the y value) for the action that was played. For all other actions, I don’t have the “ground truth” for them. 
What is the best practice in training my nn in that case?

Comment: You should learn about a subject called “reinforcement learning”. A good description of what to do exactly in the situation you describe above can be found here: http://karpathy.github.io/2016/05/31/rl/ . Essentially, you play for a while and take the actions actually sampled by the NN as “ground truth” in the loss function and then you multiply the gradient with the reward. Unfortunately, the n-armed bandit is a special situation where every episode is of length 1 (after only one action you start a new game) which makes some assertions look weird but the concepts are still valid...